# Simulate Keyboard Button Press [SDL Library]

Tags: c, sdl, keyboard-events, sdl-2

I am trying to simulate an SDL keyboard button press (using C). I have looked up the SDL info pages online but I still don't have anything that consistently works.

I have the following (removed the interrupt handling, creation of windows etc.)

```
while(1){
    SDL_Event user_event;
    user_event.type = SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT;

    SDL_PushEvent(&user_event);
    SDL_PumpEvents();

    const Uint8 *state = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

    if (state[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT]) {
        printf("LEFT PRESSED");
    }
    if (state[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT]) {
        printf("RIGHT PRESSED");
    }
}
```

I never see the 'LEFT PRESSED' string printed out, although when I press the right arrow key (from keyboard) I see the respective output generated. It appears like the left key press is never being pushed on the state var.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably you don't have english keyboard and your scancodes are different. Try `SDL_GetScancodeFromKey()` to get scancode from keycodes. Reference: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetScancodeFromKey?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryKeyboard%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29

Comment: Event type is certainly incorrect, but anyway - [documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PushEvent) explicitly states `Note: Pushing device input events onto the queue doesn't modify the state of the device within SDL.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it works like that. The state array returned by `SDL_GetKeyboardState()` represents the state of the raw keyboard, and pushing events would not affect that (even though the keyboard input generates events).

But I think it is possible to do what you want, if you can use `SDL_PollEvent()` instead of `SDL_PumpEvents()` and checking the keyboard state array,

```
/* Push a single left key event. */
SDL_Event sdlevent = {};
sdlevent.type = SDL_KEYDOWN;
sdlevent.key.keysym.sym = SDLK_LEFT;
SDL_PushEvent(&sdlevent);

while (1) {
    SDL_Event ev;
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&ev)) {
        if(ev.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
            if (ev.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_LEFT) {
                printf("LEFT PRESSED\n");
            }
            if (ev.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RIGHT) {
                printf("RIGHT PRESSED\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```